# Generated rspec test fails when testing POST with invalid params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new with rails and trying to complete the generated rspec tests for my controller `garden` with invalid parameters.

I want `square_feet` to always be supplied, but the error I'm getting appears to be complaining that there is no default value for the `gardens` table.  This confuses me; I don't want to set a default value for `square_feet` and I don't understand why the application isn't erroring out and redirecting the user when it sees a null value?

The only part of the generated test that I edited is the `let()` statements.  What do I have to do to get these tests to pass?

**Rspec test**:

```
RSpec.describe GardensController, type: :controller do

  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:garden) }
  let(:invalid_attributes) { {:name => nil, :square_feet => nil, :zone => nil} }
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with invalid params" do

      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved garden as @garden" do
        post :create, {:garden => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:garden)).to be_a_new(Garden)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
        post :create, {:garden => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(response).to render_template("new")
      end      

    end
  end

end
```

**Factory**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :garden do
    name "MyString"
    square_feet 1
    zone 1
    garden_type "MyString"
    user nil
  end
end
```

**DB Schema**:

```
mysql> describe gardens;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| square_feet | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zone        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| garden_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Rspec errors**:

```
1) GardensController POST #create with invalid params assigns a newly created but unsaved garden as @garden
     Failure/Error: if @garden.save

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: Field 'square_feet' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `gardens` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-04-26 11:25:08', '2016-04-26 11:25:08')
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:29:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:91:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   Field 'square_feet' doesn't have a default value
     #   ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'

  2) GardensController POST #create with invalid params re-renders the 'new' template
     Failure/Error: if @garden.save

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: Field 'square_feet' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `gardens` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-04-26 11:25:08', '2016-04-26 11:25:08')
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:29:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:96:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   Field 'square_feet' doesn't have a default value
     #   ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'

  3) GardensController PUT #update with invalid params assigns the garden as @garden
     Failure/Error: if @garden.update(garden_params)

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: Column 'square_feet' cannot be null: UPDATE `gardens` SET `square_feet` = NULL, `zone` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2016-04-26 11:25:08' WHERE `gardens`.`id` = 101
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:43:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:131:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   Column 'square_feet' cannot be null
     #   ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'

  4) GardensController PUT #update with invalid params re-renders the 'edit' template
     Failure/Error: if @garden.update(garden_params)

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: Column 'square_feet' cannot be null: UPDATE `gardens` SET `square_feet` = NULL, `zone` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2016-04-26 11:25:08' WHERE `gardens`.`id` = 102
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
     # ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:43:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:137:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   Column 'square_feet' cannot be null
     #   ./app/controllers/gardens_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'

Finished in 0.17718 seconds (files took 3 seconds to load)
16 examples, 4 failures, 1 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:90 # GardensController POST #create with invalid params assigns a newly created but unsaved garden as @garden
rspec ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:95 # GardensController POST #create with invalid params re-renders the 'new' template
rspec ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:129 # GardensController PUT #update with invalid params assigns the garden as @garden
rspec ./spec/controllers/gardens_controller_spec.rb:135 # GardensController PUT #update with invalid params re-renders the 'edit' template
```

Comment: There are a few errors here, for instance your update test says `square_feet can't be null` which lines up with your schema.

Comment: @Anthony: Is that an error?  I also believe `square_feet` should not be null.  It is not null in `:valid_attributes` and it is null (rightly, it seems) in `:invalid_attributes`.  Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `:invalid_attributes`?  If it shouldn't contain things like `:square_feet => null`, what should it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle exception from within the controller method, so:

```
let(:invalid_create) { post :create, {:garden => invalid_attributes}, valid_session }

it { expect(invalid_create).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) }
```

in case you wish to trap exception in controller use [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) definition:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, :with => :render_statement_invalid
```

Comment: Hm, ok.  The way those tests are generated, I was assuming that upon receiving invalid attributes, the application would somehow know to redirect the user to the create page.  But maybe it's actually up to me to write the logic to detect and address the error, with the ultimate result being that the user is redirected to the create page?